# Out of memory when using Hibernate save a large rescord?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc

My project parse XML file from [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/) , it about 1GB to save in ORM database, so I use SAXP for reading information like (paper'author, paper'infomation ......).

The function reading is OK but when I using hibernate to save information to database it have error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space "

Comment: I have been edit mapping

Comment: Post the actual mappings. And the full stack trace of the exception. How can anyone help you if you don't even show the error?

Comment: sorry for  absent information of my previous post, i just added now

Comment: So the exception happens inside AuthorBO constructor, that's progress. What are you doing in that constructor?

Comment: When i brown in database it insert, but it' run about 2 minute throw out of memory (i have been insert class Author bo)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5427/discussion-between-tiendv-and-strelok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace  , it seems that the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is not due to Hibernate because  it happens when the `SessionFactory` is built.

I think it is due to the big size XML you are parsing . You can verify it by parsing a smaller XML. If it can be saved , you can isolate the problem is not caused by Hibernate .

You can increase the maximum heap size of your Vm by using the -Xmx parameter , for example:

```
java -Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Thanks your reply . When i run a xml file 1MB it run OK, but when i run xml file 10MB it throw memory, so without hava al big Ram ~~!, any idea for this situation? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to increase the maximum heap size of your Vm  by `-Xmx` parameter?

Comment: yes , i did , but it throw same error

I have try your suggest another post but ....... same eror
 protected void commitAndClose() {
        if (session != null) {
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                if ( i % 50 == 0 ) { //50, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                        session.flush();
                        session.clear();
                }               
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }

Comment: I do this solution to  but it' can't fix proplem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion

Answer (score 2):

you should use stateless sessions for such large data sets. please read about it at [jboss website](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)