# create/update DB schema with hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, schema

I am working on a product that uses hibernate (4.2) and mysql (Amazon RDS).
the schema is updated via liquibase whenever a change is made. it also hosts many tanents through different schemas in the same DB instance.
each time a new customer is registered a new schema is built. two things should happen:

1) create the schema

2) fill the schema with static data

currently, the schema update is done by hibernate (hbm2ddl update) and the filling of static data is done by code. I don't like both solutions as I understand hbm is limited and I don't like static data changes to be code related.

are there any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: why don't you add the data through liquibase ?

Answer (score 0):

> It's always recommended to generate the schema manually, preferably by a tool supporting database schema revisions, such as the great [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/). Generating the schema from the entities is great in theory, but were fragile in practice and causes lots of problems in the long run(trust me on this).

[Hibernate/JPA DB Schema Generation Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585641/hibernate-jpa-db-schema-generation-best-practices)

*I can paste this link as comment but most probably this would be an answer.*

Comment: what about adding the static data?

Comment: you can do it after you create schema manually :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893156/best-way-to-save-the-large-number-of-records-in-hibernate/15893676#15893676