# Very slow activation of Spring Data JPA saveAll / save methods with Spring boot 2 and mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Spring boot app is using Hibernate JPA to save records to MySQL.

After working good and fast, the `save()` suddenly started to work very *very* slowly: about 10 minutes for inserting 1K records (the primary key is the ID).

I though the problem was in calling the `save()` in a loop, so I changed to `saveAll()`, but to my surprise there is no difference and it can take even **20 minutes** to save **1139 records**.

The MySQL is local and is used only by my dev env.

Here is the log file:

```
2018-08-07 14:44:25:335 - About to save all new 1139 cats of Oscar 
2018-08-07 15:03:47:758 - Succeded saving the cats of Oscar
2018-08-07 15:07:41:961 - Session Metrics {
    600922575 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1140 JDBC connections;
    92320112 nanoseconds spent releasing 1139 JDBC connections;
    312825484 nanoseconds spent preparing 2283 JDBC statements;
    464811479497 nanoseconds spent executing 2279 JDBC statements;
    233368433210 nanoseconds spent executing 229 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    233765441110 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1139 entities and 0 collections);
    40198 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

I added these to the properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Here is the code in the Service method:

```
    log.debug("About to save all new {} cats of {} ", allCats.size(), owner);
    catsRepository.saveAll(allCats);
    log.debug("Succeded saving the cats of {}", owner);
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893156/best-way-to-save-the-large-number-of-records-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

The batch size will not have an effect.

Here the important part from the hibernate doc:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch-insert

**Batch inserts**

When you make new objects persistent, employ methods flush() and clear() to the session regularly, to control the size of the first-level cache.

Example 3. Flushing and clearing the Session

```
EntityManager entityManager = null;
EntityTransaction txn = null;
try {
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

    txn = entityManager.getTransaction();
    txn.begin();

    int batchSize = 25;

    for ( int i = 0; i < entityCount; i++ ) {
        if ( i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0 ) {
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }

        Person Person = new Person( String.format( "Person %d", i ) );
        entityManager.persist( Person );
    }

    txn.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if ( txn != null && txn.isActive()) txn.rollback();
        throw e;
} finally {
    if (entityManager != null) {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```