# Activating hibernate.jdbc.batch_size

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm working on a enooooormous project.
Spring is managing transaction through AOP I'd like to use some batch insertion but I found this in the xml configuration file :

```
<!-- Turn batching off for better error messages under PostgreSQL -->
<!-- hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 -->
```

Will it changes the behavior of some other hibernate use if I activate it to 100?

Basically I never use seesion or transaction, spring is taking care of this.
all I do is someDao.save() or someDao.update().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will change behavior of all queries.

`hibernate batch size` is use to instruct hibernate that it will fire queries in specific batch size.

Refer this question you will get more clear

[Hibernate batch size confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion)