# Massive insert with JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, batch-insert

I need to do a massive insert using EJB 3, Hibernate, Spring Data and Oracle. Originally, I am using Spring Data and code is below:

```
talaoAITDAO.save(taloes);
```

Where talaoAITDAO is a Spring Data [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) subclass and taloes is a Collection of TalaoAIT entity. In this entity, Its respective ID has this form:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID_TALAO_AIT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_TALAO_AIT", sequenceName = "SQ_TALAO_AIT", allocationSize = 1000)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_TALAO_AIT")
private Long id;
```

Also this entity has no related entities to do cascade insert.

My problem here, is that all entities are individually inserted (such as `INSERT INTO TABLE(col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`). Occasionally, it can cause a timeout and all insertions will be rolled back. I would want convert these individual inserts in batch inserts (such as `INSERT INTO TABLE(col1, col2) VALUES (val11, val12), (val21, val22), (val31, val32), ...`).

Studying alternatives to improve performance, I found [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) in hibernate documentation, beyond 
[Hibernate batch size confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion) and [this other page](http://abramsm.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/hibernate-batch-processing-why-you-may-not-be-using-it-even-if-you-think-you-are/). Based on them, I wrote this code:

```
Session session = super.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
int batchSize = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < taloes.size(); i++) {
    TalaoAIT talaoAIT = taloes.get(i);
    session.save(talaoAIT);
    if(i % batchSize == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
    taloes.add(talaoAIT);
}
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

Also, in peristence.xml, I added these properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="1000" />
<property name="order_inserts" value="true" />
```

However, although in my tests I had perceived a subtle difference (mainly with big collections and big batch sizes), it was not so big as desirable. In logging console, I saw that Hibernate continued to do individual inserts, not replacing them for massive insert. As in my entity, I am using a Sequence generator I believe that it is not problem (according Hibernate documentation, I would had problem if I was using Identity generator).

So, my question is what can be missing here. Some configuration? Some method not used?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso.

Comment: Why are you unwrapping the `session`? You can do `flush()` and `clear()` on the `entityManager` directly. BUT: Usually doing big inserts with java is the wrong way; dumping everything to file, transferring these to the destination server and bulk loading usually works better. That said, occasionally you actually need to do some transformation in code; this is perhaps one of those cases.

Comment: I would first trim down the batch size to something more reasonable (like 50). Then enable DEBUG logging for hibernate and see what is happeing. Also make sure that you have a database (and JDBC Driver) that support batch updates. Which database and hibernate version are you using?

Comment: If I remember that correct, then you will find single insert-statements for each entity in the log even if bulkinserts are used. If you enable <category name="org.hibernate"><priority value="DEBUG" /> </category> you should see some special informations about batch updates. Something like "[AbstractBatcher] Executing batch size: 5" and "[Expectations] success of batch update unknown: 0"

Comment: M. Deinium: I am using Hibernate 4.1.9 with oracle 11.2. About Sequence, as I defined allocationSize in SequenceGenerator as 1000, it will be called every 1000 inserts.

Comment: Hi any update on this so far.. ? I have the same issue i have updated each configuriation correctly but still spring data jpa generationg multiple insert statements.

Comment: You can always fallback to HQL, see my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357298/320761).

Answer (score 16):

A couple of things.

First your configuration properties are wrong `order_inserts` must be `hibernate.order_inserts` . Currently your setting is ignored and you haven't changed a thing.

Next use the `EntityManager` instead of doing all that nasty hibernate stuff. The `EntityManager` also has a `flush` and `clear` method. This should at least cleanup your method. Without the order this helps a little to cleanup the session and preventing dirty-checks on all the objects in there.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
int batchSize = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < taloes.size(); i++) {
    TalaoAIT talaoAIT = taloes.get(i);
    em.persist(talaoAIT);
    if(i % batchSize == 0) {
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
    taloes.add(talaoAIT);
}
em.flush();
em.clear();
```

Next you shouldn't make your batches to large as that can cause memory problems, start with something like 50 and test which/what performs best. There is a point at which dirty-checking is going to take more time then flusing and clearing to the database. You want to find this sweet spot.

Comment: Indeed, write a loop with batchsize is between 20 and 50 and in that loop do a 'flush' and a 'clear'. Also, the hibernate property should be the same batch size : <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="xxx" />

Comment: How do you get your entityManager? I keep getting a javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException error when I try to flush

Comment: So at first I tried using @PersistentContext EntityManager entityManager to wire up the entity manager but then I wasn't allowed to flush using a shared entity manager. So I followed a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606608/how-to-manually-start-a-transaction-on-a-shared-entitymanager-in-spring and it just hangs

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted by M. Deinum worked great for me, provided I set the following Hibernate properties in my JPA `persistence.xml` file:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
```

I am using an Oracle database, so I also have this one defined:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a promising small library for batching inserts with Hibernate and Postgresql. It is called [pedal-dialect](https://github.com/eclecticlogic/pedal-dialect) and uses the Postgresql - command `COPY` which is claimed by many people to be much faster than batched inserts (references: [Postgresql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/populate.html), [Postgresql Insert Strategies - Performance Test](https://insights.project-a.com/postgresql-insert-strategies-performance-test-7ae63d8ad148), [How does copy work and why is it so much faster than insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715354/how-does-copy-work-and-why-is-it-so-much-faster-than-insert)). pedal-dialect allows to use `COPY` without fully losing the ease of use of Hibernate. You still get automatic mapping of entities and rows and don't have to implement it on your own.