# Is there a way to use batch inserts in JPA?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have thousands of SELECT statements that are executed one after the other, and it takes a lot of time in doing this(the query can be seen below), quering the DB multiple times, and also it is not possible to have a single query.

```
Query q = mEntityManager.createNativeQuery(newQuery);           
List<Object> results = q.getResultList();
```

These statemenmts go inside a dynamic loop, which creates thousands of queries, is there a way to run them in batches, like we do it for insert and delete ?

Comment: for batch insert refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285347/massive-insert-with-jpa-hibernate)