# Using batch insert in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Well, i'm trying to making a batch insert in JPA but i think this don't work.

My method is this :

```
public void saveBatch(List<? extends AbstractBean> beans) {
    try {
        begin();
        logger.info("Salvando em batch " + beans.size() + " bean(s)");
        for (int i = 0; i < beans.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
        entityManager.merge(beans.get(i));

        }
        commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar batch. MSG ORIGINAL: "
                + e.getMessage());
        rollback();
        throw new DAOException("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar batch");
    }
    }
```

My ideia is that each 50 rows the hibernate will make:

```
insert into tableA values (),(),()...
```

But watching the log i see one INSERT for each merge() command link this:

```
insert into tableA values ()
insert into tableA values ()
insert into tableA values ()
insert into tableA values ()
```

What is wrong ? This is correct ?

Comment: what is your JPA impl. It is depending on.
Have you modify your JPA conf to enable it ?
If yes, how ?

Comment: my jpa is 2.1, using hibernate. I not modified nothing in jpa config.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285347/massive-insert-with-jpa-hibernate

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. Hibernate will not generate a single bulky SQL statement but it will rather take a batch of (insert) statements (50 in your case) and pass them onto the database simultaneously in a single round trip (when `EntityManager#flush()` (or commit at the end) is executed)

Comment: I read this post but i am already using entityManager and a lowest value batch size = 50

Comment: @Tiny if your logic is correct, so the problem is solved but this is at least strange because hibernante is showing inserts before real inserts sql

Comment: I did not get anything from this, "*Hibernante is showing inserts before real inserts sql*".

Comment: Because for me hibernate should show INSERT statement only when really touch the database

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not enable batching by default. You will want to consider the following [settings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties) (I think at least `batch_size` is required to get any batch inserts/updates to work):

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size
```

> A non-zero value enables use of JDBC2 batch updates by Hibernate. e.g.
>   recommended values between 5 and 30

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data
```

> Set this property to true if your JDBC driver returns correct row
>   counts from executeBatch(). It is usually safe to turn this option on.
>   Hibernate will then use batched DML for automatically versioned data.
>   Defaults to false. e.g. true | false

```
hibernate.order_updates (similarly, hibernate.order_inserts)
```

> Forces Hibernate to order SQL updates by the primary key value of the
>   items being updated. This will result in fewer transaction deadlocks
>   in highly concurrent systems. e.g. true | false

Comment: I added batch_size in persistente.xml but the problem continue. I cant understand why i should use this property if i am controlling it.