# How to insert bulk data in database using hibernate and spring DAO pattern

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

I am working on an application which is using Spring DAO + hibernate structure to deal with database.

I want to insert bulk of rows (20000 approx) in oracle database using hibernate, but using .save() is very slow.

I learned that using StateLess session this can be done, but because all sessions are managed through BaseDaoImp class, i don't know how to create stateless sessions in this design pattern.

Please help if anybody knows how to implement this.

Comment: Use Hibernate native query by managing transaction.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit how to do  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `entityManager.flush()` and `entityManager.clear()` after every n-th call to the `save()` method. 
If you use hibernate then add `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` and set it to equal n. 100 might be enough but it is your choice.

see:
[Massive insert with JPA + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285347/massive-insert-with-jpa-hibernate) or http://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/

Answers are quite old but seems work fine.

Comment: Session object are managed internally through BaseDaoI.java (DAO object), and i cannot make changes to it. all i have is methods, .persist .save etc etc to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, it was was similar to approach we using in JDBC batching..

```
public Long save(HttpServletRequest request) {

**//Further business logic here....**
for ( int i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
                     getEntityManager().persist((ABC) model);

            if ( i > 0 && i % 2500== 0 ) {
                               getEntityManager().flush();
                               getEntityManager().clear();
                          }
                  }
                     tx.commit();
                   ((EntityManager) session).close();
    }
```