# Using PostgreSQL COPY instead of INSERT with Sequelize.bulkCreate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

Read [several sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715354/how-does-copy-work-and-why-is-it-so-much-faster-than-insert) stating how `COPY` is faster than `INSERT` statements in PostgreSQL when performing bulk ingests. [Sequelize.js](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) has a `bulkCreate()` function for doing bulk INSERTs.

Is it possible for Sequelize to do `COPY` instead of `INSERT`, and do you expect `COPY` to be faster? I am ingesting 10,000-1,000,000 rows at a time in each of the 5 parallel processes running for a total of 2 hours. Hope some speedups can be achieved using `COPY` and Sequelize.

*Actual database is using TimescaleDB extension*

**Example Code**

```
let Note = sequelize.define('notes', {
    description: Sequelize.STRING
});

let notes = [
    { description: 'Tai chi in the morning' },
    { description: 'Visited friend' },
    { description: 'Went to cinema' },
    { description: 'Listened to music' },
    { description: 'Watched TV all day' },
    { description: 'Walked for a hour' },
];

Note.bulkCreate(notes, { logging: console.log }).then(() => {
    console.log('notes created');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
}).finally(() => {
    sequelize.close();
});
```

**Generated SQL**

```
INSERT INTO "notes" ("id","description") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Tai chi in the morning'),
(DEFAULT,'Visited friend'),(DEFAULT,'Went to cinema'),(DEFAULT,'Listened to music'),
(DEFAULT,'Watched TV all day'),(DEFAULT,'Walked for a hour') RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Can you find the bottleneck?  If the bottleneck is firing triggers or maintaining indexes, switching from INSERT to COPY will not make much difference.

Comment: @jjanes What is the recommended method for finding the bottleneck in this case? `pg_stat_statements`?