# Hibernate JDBC Batch size is not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringFramework 3 and Hibernate 4 and MySQL 5 with jpa. My test code looks like...

```
@Repository
public class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void insertBulk() {
     Item it;
     for(int i= 0; i<1000;i++) {
        it = new Item();
        it.setPrice(Math.random()*100);
        em.persist(it);
     }
  }
}
```

My spring configuration

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="application" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="application" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.springapp.test.domain.Item</class>
    <class>com.springapp.test.domain.Order</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When I call run my code it will fires insert query 1000 times instead of firing 50 insert query. What is the issue?
Please help me to batch insert in jpa using hibernate

Answer (score 3):

add logger `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch` in level debug.
hibernate can generate batches with size 1 or 2 in case of wrong order of inserts.
try to use `hibernate.order_inserts=true hibernate.order_updates=true`

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood "batch size". Batch size means send "batch size" number of queries together in one go instead of sending each query as the code fires the query. Therefore in this case there will be 1000 insert queries, sent 50 times with 20 insert queries in each batch.

Comment: I want to do like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion?answertab=votes#tab-top)